# Swift auto layout programmatically and dynamic

Tags: swift, autolayout, programmatically-created

I have a View where I load buttons dynamically. So I have a for loop to loop through all buttons. Since this is dynamically I want to create the auto layout programmatically. Right now I have the following code:

```
for var i = 0; i < data.count; i++ {
      let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
      button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

      button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

      self.view.addSubview(button)

      let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

      let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant:15)

      let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

      let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:100)

      scrollView.addConstraints([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

This creates the first button and places it 15px under the top bar. The problem I have is how to place the next button 15px under the first one, the third button 15px under the second one etc. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thats definitely possible, but firstly, I should mention it's not required that you add constraints for the buttons' width and height since they have an intrinsic content size (like `UILabel`) which depends on attributes such their text and font.

**Back to your problem!**

Here's the code, the explanation for each step is below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1.
    var upperView: UIView = scrollView

    for i in 0..<data.count {
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        //  2.
        scrollView.addSubview(button)

        //  3.
        let attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = i == 0 ? .Top : .Bottom

        //  4.
        let topEdgeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: upperView,
            attribute: attribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 15.0)

        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: scrollView,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0)

        scrollView.addConstraint(topEdgeConstraint)
        scrollView.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)

        //  5.
        if i == data.count - 1 {
            let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                attribute: .Bottom,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: scrollView,
                attribute: .Bottom,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: -15.0)

            scrollView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
        }

        upperView = button
    }
}
```

**1.** `upperView` is used to keep track of the view 'above' the current button. For example, when the first button is created, the `upperView` is the `UIScrollView` For the second button, `upperView` is the first button; for the third button, `upperView` is the second button and so on...

**2.** Your buttons should be added to the `UIScrollView`, not the `self.view`. Otherwise you'll get the error:

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint...

**3.** This line selects the attribute on the `upperView` that will relate the `button` to the `upperView`. Here's a picture to demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

- **a)** The `.Top` of the button is related to the `.Top` of the `UIScrollView.`
- **b)** The `.Top` of the button is related to the `.Bottom` of the previous `UIButton`.

**4.** Making the top and centre X constraints - that's all pretty self explanatory.

**5.** For the `UIScrollView` to correctly calculate its `contentSize` it must have constraints in an unbroken chain from it top to bottom (the top to the bottom, in this case, because it needs to scroll vertically). Therefore, if it's the last `UIButton` a constraint from its bottom edge is added to the `UIScrollView`'s bottom edge.

Hope that helps!